# Change default controller file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework for my project. While working with CodeIgniter, i found that "Welcome.php" is the default controller file in CodeIgniter. But i want to make another file "Home.php" as my default controller.

I tried changing 
`$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';` to
`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`
in the "routes.php" file in config folder but it didn't work.

Comment: can you show your home controller?

Comment: its should work, can you show how your Home.php looks like?

Comment: Elaborate on *it didn't work*.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#reserved-routes)

If you are using `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';` then it will call

`Welcome::index()`

So, as you are changing to

`$route['default_controller'] = 'home';`

You should have `Home::index()`